# Uma imageview receber imagem de acordo com a opção selecionada

Tags: java, android, imageview

Gostaria que pudessem me iluminar em uma situação.
Quero alterar a imagem de uma ImageView. Até consigo faze-lo através do:

```
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageChm);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
```

porem, eu tenho mais algumas imagens (img1, img2, img3, img4 ... img 50)
Gostaria que eles usasem o mesmo espaço, por isso decidir adaptar todas a só imageView, no meu caso a imageChm, cada imagem seria indicada por um button. Ex: ao clicar no button1 a imagem que apareceria seria img1, ao clicar no button2 a imagem sera img2 e assim por diante.
Como posso trocar o endereço da imagem `(R.drawable.img1) de forma dinamica ao clicar nos botões respectivos.`

LEMBRANDO QUE NO MEU CASO O BOTÃO E A IMAGEVIEW ESTAO EM ACTIVITY DIFERENTES

Answer (score 0):

Seta um `onClickListener` em cada botão.

Ao entrar nesse método, seta a imagem.

Por exemplo, no `onClickListener` do botão 1:

```
   btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
    }
});
```

No botão 2:

```
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2);
    }
});
```

E assim por diante.

Comment: eu fiz dois testes.. um com um botão dentro da activity e funcionou, outro teste foi com o botão em outra activity e nesse caso não funcionou... sabe o motivo disto acontecer?

Comment: Aí já é outra pergunta... Mas, se vc quer apertar o botão em uma activity pra mudar em outra, vai ter que criar uma classe e setar uma propriedade.